# upgrade OS and SQL Server version on SQL Cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, upgrade

We have a critical application that uses SQL Server 2016 Cluster running on Windows server 2012. In order for us to upgrade the application, we need to upgrade the OS and the SQL Server version. What will be best option with minimal down time to upgrade the OS to windows 2019 /2022 and the database to SQL Server 2019. We are using Physical servers. Also we are planning to use Always-On instead of fail over cluster.

Comment: "Also we are planning to use Always-On instead of fail over cluster" always-on is more like a marketing term instead of a feature. always-on includes both Failover cluster and availability groups. They protect against different types of failure. instance level and database level respectively

Comment: How many servers are involved in the cluster?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is not nearly enough detail provided - upgrading is a deep and broad topic that can be approached many different ways depending on your requirements.  If you can, add details to your question including the options you are contemplating, including using new servers, upgrading the O/S directly, how much down-time you can withstand, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The best way, with the least downtime, would be to build new servers and install the latest version of SQL. This is true for several reasons.

1. **Rollback** If anything goes wrong, you can simply revert connection strings back to the old server.
2. **Fresh start** Lots of legacy crud starts to build up on servers over the years. Building fresh servers gives you a chance to rid yourself of that. Similar to how a lot of Windows users like to do a fresh install n their desktop once a year or so.
3. **Testing** You can have the new servers built, configured, tested and ready to go. This gives you the perfect opportunity to perform a few dry runs and make sure the apps work against the new server.
4. **Quick cutover** Once the servers are fully configured and tested, you can set up Log Shipping from the old server to the new servers and plan a time to cut over to the new database server. Using Log Shipping, downtime can be reduced down to about 15 minutes, depending on the size of the databases and how you choose to repoint the application connection strings. One option it is stand up a DNS alias that point all connections to the new server, or listener (if applicable).

Comment: you might be able to avoid repointing applications at all by just changing the cluster name on new cluster to same name of old cluster.

Comment: @BobKlimes good point.

Comment: Upvoted, this is what we follow whenever we have to upgrade our server or database including comment made by Bob Klimes. We get down-time for a minimal period - restore transaction log in that window and assign same host name and IP to the new server after switching off old server(we assign different host name and IP, it also helps in case something was missed out or misconfigured).